# With customer community license, share record with 2 contacts

Tags: apex, community, sharing, customer-community, customer-portal

On case, I have 2 lookup fields on case: Contact and Case_Contact__c

The contact will always be the person who is creating case. The case contact can be any contact selected by customer.

Once a case is created, we are changing the owner to queue.

I have created a sharing set to assign the access to contact based on current user login. How I can give access to the other user whose contact is present in Case_Contact__c field of case?

We are using customer community license (Not plus one).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply multiple sharing set on one object same profile](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310984/apply-multiple-sharing-set-on-one-object-same-profile)

Comment: @PrzemysławDługoszewski-Tamoń That answer applies to partner community.  Customer Community can't use manual sharing rules.